# Javascript function & nested functions

Tags: javascript, function, scope

**Purpose:** I need to call sub function within main one;

**Function declaration:**

```
var MainFunction = function () {

   function NestedFunc1(){
       console.warn("NestedFunc1");
   };

   function NestedFunc2(){
       console.warn("NestedFunc2");
   }; 
}
```

**Functions call:**

MainFunction.NestedFunc1();

MainFunction.NestedFunc2();

- *What am I doing wrong?*

10x;

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* Pretty much everything, You're fundamentally confused about the difference between a nested function and an object property. *I need to call sub function within main one.* But that's not what you're then doing; you're trying to invoke a property on the main function. By the way, do you intend for `MainFunction` to do something itself, or just be a sort of container? PS. Functions don't end in semi-colons; if you put one there, it just creates an empty statement;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make it public via a property then

```
function MainFunction  () {

   this.nestedFunc1 = function(){
       console.warn("NestedFunc1");
   };

   this.nestedFunc2 = function(){
       console.warn("NestedFunc2");
   };

}
```

now you can invoke this function outside by doing

```
var malObj = new MainFunction();
malObj.nestedFunc1();
```

However, if you want to still invoke it like `MainFunction.NestedFunc1()` then make it

```
var MainFunction = {

   NestedFunc1:function (){
       console.warn("NestedFunc1");
   },

   NestedFunc2:function (){
       console.warn("NestedFunc2");
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that both of those functions are isolated within a function scope. Think of them as private functions.

One (of many) solutions could be to define MainFunction as a plain ol' object that has some functions as attributes:

```
var MainFunction = {
   NestedFunction1: function () { .. },
   NestedFunction2: function () { .. }
};
```

Notice that a comma is needed to separate the functions because of the way we are defining them. You then just call

```
MainFunction.NestedFunction1();
```

Also note that this pattern is fine as long as you don't wish to have other "private" functions inside that object.